# Multiple associated accounts messing with my desired display name

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I joined Stack Exchange with an account on Stack Overflow (for programming) for which I have a desired username (which you can see now). Then I opened an account for BH, and set a different username for that, but wanting to keep my stackoverflow username and it was working. Then yesterday I registered on Chemistry with my account, and it used my BH username (and account details/description.. etc). So, trying to fix that, I somehow set my BH details to the other account details and then I realized this and tried to fix it. Now I can't, because you can only change your username once every 30 days.. ugh.

So, how do I now fix this and prevent this from happening again? How do I get my new associated network accounts to use my Stack Overflow details and keep my BH details intact (and different)?

Answer (score 5):

You probably copied a change to all profiles by mistake. The best thing to do is to [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to get it straightened out.

Tell us the user name you want on BH, and the one you want everywhere else, and we can get it sorted out pretty quickly.

The guard is there just to prevent users causing confusion by constantly changing their user names, if you end up in a pinch through an honest mistake, we'll help you get it sorted out.

Comment: great, thanks, I have used the contact form. However, I am still curious to know how I can have one set of information to be used as the default for when I create new accounts. ie, I want to prevent new accounts from using the BH details, and instead use the stackoverflow details.

Comment: @insaner I'm checking on that now

Comment: ok, it seems that the details in my "network" account are affected by this too, and this is perhaps the cause of some of this, but I can't find where to edit it (it's not editable).